# Does visual studio supports outlet collections in iOS designer?

Tags: c#, ios, .net, visual-studio

In Xcode I can assign a number of controls to an outlet array using an outlet collection.

Does Visual Studio iOS designer supports outlet collections too?

If not, how can I assign a predefined set of controls (e.g. buttons) to an array of UIButton similarly how the outlet collection does?

Comment: Is this a Xamarin question?

Comment: It is indeed. Visual Studio for Mac, iOS Designer.